# Stub getCurrentPosition with sinonJS and force it to fail

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, sinon

```
 $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
```

I managed to stub it and get specified results like this

```
$window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = sinon.stub().callsArgWith(0, mockedResponse );
```

then calling the function that call's that service and following with with a 
     $rootScope.$apply();
I'm getting my results, back.

Problem is though that from sinon Documentation, I don't understand how stub.throws() work and how can I make getCurrentPosition to fail.

```
$window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = sinon.stub().throws( "I'm a happy error");
```

look s that registers the stubbed error message but it doesn't tell to that service to fail.